# How to interpret the mass conservation equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to know that the difference is between the following equations:

$$ \frac{\delta h_d}{\delta t} = -\nabla.(\vec{v_s} h_d) = -u_s(\frac{\delta h_d}{\delta x}) -v_s(\frac{\delta h_d}{\delta y}) - h_d(\frac{\delta u_s}{\delta x}) - h_d(\frac{\delta v_s}{\delta y})$$

$$ \frac{\delta h_d}{\delta t} = -\vec{v_s}.\nabla(h_d) = -u_s(\frac{\delta h_d}{\delta x}) -v_s(\frac{\delta h_d}{\delta y})$$

Here, $\vec{v_s}$ is the 2D velocity vector with components $u_s$ and $v_s$, and $h_d$ the thickness of a rock layer that is being advected. How does the addition of the last 2 terms in the first equation change the physical meaning of the equation? Does it make a ddifference if the velocity field is constant or non-constant in time?

Comment: I really don't want to be offensive, but asking about "physical meaning" at a mathematics site is... erm... rather optimistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach to understanding this is usually by considering the first equation to be "more fundamental":

$$ \frac{\delta h_d}{\delta t} = -\nabla \cdot (\vec{v_s} h_d)$$

since it describes mass conservation. (You might need to multiply both sides with a $\rho$ here for the mass density to get the right units but it doesn't matter if we consider the density to be constant, which is usually OK for water.)

By using the product rule for differential operators on the right-hand-side of this equation we get:

$$-\nabla \cdot (\vec{v_s} h_d)=-(\nabla\cdot \vec{v_s}) h_d-\vec{v_s} \cdot \nabla h_d$$

Now, if the fluid is incompressible we have that:
$$\nabla\cdot \vec{v_s}=0$$

So, under these circumstances we get:

$$-\nabla \cdot (\vec{v_s} h_d)=-\vec{v_s} \cdot \nabla h_d$$

In other words, the two equations are equivalent if the fluid is incompressible. If the fluid is not incompressible we will need to use the "more fundamental" equation. Furthermore, if the density is not constant we need to include it and get additional terms including the gradient of the density, and so on.